# Can't access variables inside same block of code in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I know this is basic but I am new to Blazor and I don't get the concept, why can't I access this variable. And if this is meant to be like this what are the benefits of this. The code is inside one block and I can't access Test.

```
@code{
    Service.Service1Client Client = new Service.Service1Client();
    int Test = 4;
    Test++;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting? The problem is unclear, and it's not obvious how the second block of code (from your picture) is related, either.

Comment: cant see an `employee` variable in your `@code` block.. `Test++` is misplaced. You're conceptually in a `class` there; you can't run statements, only declare variables and methods

Comment: My bed I fixed it.  Error is "Test does not exist"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that the  `@code{` says `class{` instead. This is not valid C#:

```
class Something{

  int Test = 4;   //declares a class level variable called Test - not perfect, because it's a private field and shouldnt have a pascalCase name, but.. it works
  Test++;         //can't run code like that in a class level context
```

You'll have to do that `Test++` inside a method (maybe drop a button into the markup, put an `onclick="@SomeMethodName"` and put a `private void SomeMethodName(){ Test++; }` in the class. The Counter razor example should have some helpful code in

You can also do this (and I do this often because intellisense works so much nicer in VS2019):

Suppose you have in Solution Explorer:

```
Pages
+-- MyPage.razor
```

You can add a class called `MyPage.razor.cs` in the Pages folder

```
Pages
+-- MyPage.razor
    +-- MyPage.razor.cs
```

It gets put as a child of MyPage.razor

Open the class and ensure it says:

```
public partial class MyPage{

}
```

Now you can just code in there instead of in the `@code{` block.. All the things you're used to in a normal class will work there, and the markup razor file can be just for markup.. And best of all you won't have some minor syntax error in the markup (like too many `(`) clobbering your `@code` region and creating syntax errors under every line, with all kinds of weird error messages like "does not contain a constructor with that many arguments" - the Intellisense seems to work a lot better/more tolerant of minor errors/unfinished statements if you work in a codebehind `class` rather than an in-page `@code`

Comment: Ok, this makes more sense now than you so much.